# Redirecting local domains in WRT120N

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, internal-dns

I have a  WRT120N and I want that my users go to 192.168.1.108 when they type `server` in the browser. It would be great to modify the host file but I couldn't find that option in the web interface of this router.

The server I am trying to reach is connected to the router and it's running linux. I am about to run a `dns` service in that server and add it's ip to the router's static dns list.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. set a NetBIOS name of the server to 'server'
2. configure the Linux server as a DNS server for the local area network (resolve all LAN domains to IP addresses, forward the rest of the queries to your ISP DNS)
3. flash the router with dd-wrt or similar software and set the DNS server on the router.